# Solving a Simple 'Sum and Product' Problem

Tags: equation-solving, findinstance

I am trying to solve a simple 'sum and product' problem.  Basically, the sum of four prices and the product of those four prices are numerically equal (you must, of course, disregard the units).  The value of the sum/product is given.  Here is my attempt in MMA 11.3.

```
prices = {a, b, c, d}
pints = prices \[Element] Integers
ppos = prices > 0
ptotal = Total[prices] == 711
pprod = Times @@ prices == 100^3 711
FindInstance[{pints, ppos, ptotal, pprod}, prices]
```

This spins and spins without returning with an answer.

This Python code utilizing the Z3 Solver module will return within a minute with the answer.

```python
import z3    
def Find711PricesZ3(target = 7.11):
    a, b, c, d = z3.Ints('a b c d')
    s = z3.Solver()
    s.add((a + b + c + d) == target * 100)
    s.add((a * b * c * d) == target * 100**4)
    s.add(a > -1, b > -1, c > -1, d > -1)
    solvable = s.check()
    print(solvable)
    if solvable == z3.sat:
        m = s.model()
        print(m)
```

Then you run `Find711PricesZ3()` and voila!  Less than a minute later you have an answer.

What is wrong with my Mathematica formulation?

Also, I was trying to `Monitor[]` the `FindInstance[]` command with `Monitor[...,prices]` and various other alternatives, but none of those worked.  Is it possible to see which values of `prices` Mathematica is working on to know that the process is working?

Thanks so much for your assistance.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Do you not see my Mathematica code in the post?  I see it on my end.  It is above the Python code.  Let me know if you still don't see it and I will try to figure out why.

Comment: Sorry, Joe, for some reason my brain parsed it as python. <face palm>

Comment: `FindInstance` does some symbolic solving and not just a brute-force search. This shows the (first) `Reduce` command it calls: `Trace[
 FindInstance[{pints, ppos, ptotal, pprod}, prices],
 r_Reduce :> Return[Hold[r], Trace],
 TraceInternal -> True]`

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does `Trace` need to finish evaluating the expression before it returns with the first `Reduce` command it calls?  This `Trace` seems to be spinning for me again, not coming back with an answer, as if it is trying to complete the `FindInstance`.  Maybe `Trace` only returns once `expression` has been fully evaluated?

Comment: The code I posted uses `Return` to break out of `Trace` before the `Reduce` command is executed. It's very quick for me (less than 0.01 sec. according to `AbsoluteTiming`). Did you change any of your variable definitions since posting your Q? I assume you copy-pasted my code, but if you typed it in, check it. The `Hold[r]` is important because that keeps the `Reduce` command from executing.

Comment: @MichaelE2 Does the original code execute for you quickly?  Maybe my MMA is broken.  What version of MMA are you on?  (I copied/pasted code, no variable changes).

Comment: I'm using V13.0.1, Mac M1 Max  --  Your original `FindInstance` takes forever (I suppose, since I killed it after a minute).

Comment: Nice to see another FiveThirtyEight Riddler fan on this forum.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I thought I disguised this query enough to hide it!  :-P  I hope I didn't spoil the puzzle for you.  Do you have a fast running Mathematica solution?

Comment: Hehe, no worries. I tried to work through it by hand with prime factorization but it ended up being more involved than I expected and then I got called away to something else.

Answer (score 13):

Mathematica can find all the solutions.

```
Reduce[{a + b + c + d == 711, a*b*c*d == 100^3 711}, {a, b, c, 
  d}, PositiveIntegers]

%// ToRules // List
```

```
{{a -> 120, b -> 125, c -> 150, d -> 316}, {a -> 120, b -> 125, 
  c -> 316, d -> 150}, {a -> 120, b -> 150, c -> 125, 
  d -> 316}, {a -> 120, b -> 150, c -> 316, d -> 125}, {a -> 120, 
  b -> 316, c -> 125, d -> 150}, {a -> 120, b -> 316, c -> 150, 
  d -> 125}, {a -> 125, b -> 120, c -> 150, d -> 316}, {a -> 125, 
  b -> 120, c -> 316, d -> 150}, {a -> 125, b -> 150, c -> 120, 
  d -> 316}, {a -> 125, b -> 150, c -> 316, d -> 120}, {a -> 125, 
  b -> 316, c -> 120, d -> 150}, {a -> 125, b -> 316, c -> 150, 
  d -> 120}, {a -> 150, b -> 120, c -> 125, d -> 316}, {a -> 150, 
  b -> 120, c -> 316, d -> 125}, {a -> 150, b -> 125, c -> 120, 
  d -> 316}, {a -> 150, b -> 125, c -> 316, d -> 120}, {a -> 150, 
  b -> 316, c -> 120, d -> 125}, {a -> 150, b -> 316, c -> 125, 
  d -> 120}, {a -> 316, b -> 120, c -> 125, d -> 150}, {a -> 316, 
  b -> 120, c -> 150, d -> 125}, {a -> 316, b -> 125, c -> 120, 
  d -> 150}, {a -> 316, b -> 125, c -> 150, d -> 120}, {a -> 316, 
  b -> 150, c -> 120, d -> 125}, {a -> 316, b -> 150, c -> 125, 
  d -> 120}}
```

Comment: +1, I did try Reduce, but used `Integers` and it was taking long time so stopped it. did not think of trying domain `PositiveIntegers`  Mathematica beats Python again :)

Comment: Are all the solutions equivalent?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Yes, all of them are equivalent upto permutation.

Comment: Thanks,I thought maybe my eyes missed something. How long did it take?

Comment: @MichaelE2  About 10min

Comment: Ah similar. Mine took 12m. (I ran it again.) +1

Comment: MichaelE2 and @cvgmt Thanks so much for this assistance.  I am running on a very old computer.  So, maybe I was not patient enough.  If it is taking 10-15 minutes for you, then it will take at least 30 minutes for me.  I will try to let it run longer.  I wrongly assumed that since the code was so simple it would not take that long to run.  Especially since the Python version "found an instance" in about a minute.

Answer (score 10):

*Second answer*

Here's a fast way to solve the problem, working from a different angle based on the factorization of `100^3 * 711`, which obviously figures in `pprod`:

```
Extract[#, Position[Total[#, {5}], 711]] &@
   Outer[Times,
    2^Select[
      IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[2, 711]]]],
      Times @@ # == 0 &], (* at least one odd price to get 711 *)
    3^Flatten[
      Permutations /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[2, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[3, 711]]]], 1],
    5^Flatten[
      Permutations /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[5, 711]]]], 1],
    79^Flatten[
      Permutations /@ 
       IntegerPartitions[1, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[79, 711]]]], 1],
    1
    ] // Flatten // AbsoluteTiming

(*  {0.017399, {120, 316, 150, 125}}  *)
```

*First answer*

Oh, cool, while I was doing something else, this finished:

```
prices = {a, b, c, d};
pints = prices \[Element] Integers;
ppos = And @@ Thread[prices > 0];
ptotal = Total[prices] == 711;
pprod = Times @@ prices == 100^3 711;
FindInstance[{pints, ppos, ptotal, pprod, 
  0 < a < 500 && 0 < b < 500 && 0 < c < 500 && 
   0 < d < 500}, prices, Integers]

(*  {{a -> 120, b -> 125, c -> 150, d -> 316}}  *)
```

All I know is that it took a long time.  I neglected to time it.  Less than 15 minutes, I think.

Comment: Wow!  This second answer is magnificent!  I am currently digesting it.  Not often can one realize a 6000x increase in performance so soon.  Is the reason the factor 2 doesn't get permuted because one of the factors can sit still, while all the others permute around it?  That will still generate all possibilities?

Comment: @JoeMarino Re permuting `2`: Take any solution `{a, b, c, d}`. You can reorder it so that the 2-power factors appear in one of the orders given by the `Select[..]` code. I chose `2` because its partitions gave the most permutations. One could choose any of the prime factors. It just changes how many redundant solutions you get (redundant up to reordering).

Answer (score 6):

OK.  So, the original code I posted was not faulty.  I didn't have a code problem, I had an old computer problem.  As I watched in Task Manager, when Mathematica would run the original code, it would gobble up RAM, and at some point reach the limit of physical RAM on the machine.  At that point, Mathematica would begin transferring some of what was in RAM to disk (noted by a high disk % and a reduction of RAM being used).  This would repeat until terminated (I couldn't wait for this to finish; when you start using hard disk instead of RAM, you are in for a long wait).

As @MichaelE2 and @cvgmt have noted, on a modern machine, the first three iterations of the code posted will run and complete in about 10 or 15 minutes.  `FindInstance[]` is capable of finding more than one solution, and this robustness makes it slower than the Python code, which is definitely only designed to find just one solution.

We have improvements to this, of course.  MichaelE2 created a version that utilizes the factorization of the product constraint.  It runs quickly.  Since it can help a new Mathematica user (and I am kinda new to Mathematica), I'd like to break down his code for the less experienced.

The prime factors of 711 million are 2, 3, 5, and 79.

```
FactorInteger[711 100^3]
```

> {{2, 6}, {3, 2}, {5, 6}, {79, 1}}

Now each power above (6, 2, 6 and 1) is partitioned, limited by the number of times that the base will divide 711.  Only partitions of length 4 are needed, since we have four prices.

```
IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[2, 711]]]]
IntegerPartitions[2, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[3, 711]]]]
IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[5, 711]]]]
IntegerPartitions[1, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[79, 711]]]]
```

> {{6, 0, 0, 0}, {5, 1, 0, 0}, {4, 2, 0, 0}, {4, 1, 1, 0}, {3, 3, 0,
> 0}, {3, 2, 1, 0} ....

Now, we need to create permutations for three of these four (see MichaelE2's note above for why).  We'll take a look at the factor 5.

```
Permutations /@ 
  IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[5, 711]]]] // 
 Flatten[#, 1] &
```

> {{4, 2, 0, 0}, {4, 0, 2, 0}, {4, 0, 0, 2}, {2, 4, 0, 0}, {2, 0, 4,
> 0}, {2, 0, 0, 4}, {0, 4, 2, 0}, {0, 4, 0, 2}, {0, 2, 4, 0},...

Now, we raise the base factor to each of these exponents.  Then `Outer[]` does its job of making every possible combination (grab one from each list and apply the given function, here `Times[]`).

```
Outer[Times, 
 2^Select[IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[2, 711]]]], 
   Times @@ # == 0 &],(*at least one odd price to get 711*)
 3^Flatten[
   Permutations /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[2, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[3, 711]]]], 1], 
 5^Flatten[
   Permutations /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[6, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[5, 711]]]], 1], 
 79^Flatten[
   Permutations /@ 
    IntegerPartitions[1, {4}, Range[0, Floor[Log[79, 711]]]], 1], 1]
```

> {{{{{28440000, 25, 1, 1}, {360000, 1975, 1, 1}, {360000, 25, 79,    1},
> {360000, 25, 1, 79}},...

`Outer[]` has first grabbed 2^{6, 0, 0, 0}, 3^{2, 0, 0, 0}, 5^{4, 2, 0, 0}, and 79^{1, 0, 0, 0} and created the products of 2^i * 3^i * 5^i * 79^i for i = 1 to 4.  It will then change to 79^{0, 1, 0, 0}, and repeat.  It does this for all combos.

Now we only have to execute `Extract[#, Position[Total[#, {5}], 711]] &` on the result of all this.  Each item is totaled, and if that item totals 711, that location is fed to `Extract[]` to retrieve the four prices from the original, un-totaled list that are the solution.  Basically, for each set of four prices created by `Outer[]`, if the total is 711, retrieve the prices.

I know when I first started looking at compact Mathematica code, it could be daunting.  I hope this extended look at MichaelE2's solution helps the newer users out there who stumble across this later.

I am still trying to digest chyanog's solution.  I still need to decipher the first command executed, which is a lot of the secret sauce.  When I figure it out, I'll try to post back.  I can vouch that the code does work.  If you have repeated applications to make, the compiled function will be speedy.

*EDIT*

OK. I think I get it now.  Here is the first command from chyanog's solution.

```
Through[{Floor@*MinValue, Ceiling@*MaxValue}[{#, a + b + c + d == 711,
      a*b*c*d == 100^3 711, 0 < a <= b <= c <= d}, {a, b, c, d}]] & /@ {a, b, c, d}
```

So, `Through[]` is a new one for me.  So is the `Composition[]` function.  The composition, using the shorthand `@*`, is nothing more than `Floor[MinValue[...]]` and `Ceiling[MaxValue[...]`.  What `Through[]` is going to do is take these two compositions and apply them both to whatever comes next.  That means we end up taking the arguments

`{#, a + b + c + d == 711,a*b*c*d == 100^3 711, 0 < a <= b <= c <= d}, {a, b, c, d}]] &`

and feed them to both `Floor[MinValue[...]]` and `Ceiling[MaxValue[...]` (this ends up being the expression and constraints that those functions want).  What `MinValue[]` and `MaxValue[]` will do is look at the constraints it was given and provide a range of values that a variable can take and still satisfy the constraints.

The constraints were formulated as a function (note the `#` placeholder and the `&` terminator), so we can `Map[]` it (using `/@`) onto each variable separately.  We then create the pairs in the output by executing this pseudocode:

> For each *var* in *{a, b, c, d}*, find the minimum and maximum values
> that the variable takes on while satisfying the *constraints*.

The first pair in the output, {74, 131}, is created from these two commands:

```
Floor[MinValue[{a, a + b + c + d == 711,a*b*c*d == 100^3 711, 0 < a <= b <= c <= d}, {a, b, c, d}]]
```

and

```
Ceiling[MaxValue[{a, a + b + c + d == 711,a*b*c*d == 100^3 711, 0 < a <= b <= c <= d}, {a, b, c, d}]]
```

From there, I feel the code speaks for itself.

*END EDIT*

Thanks, everyone, for the valuable contributions.  If I have interpreted any of the code incorrectly, hopefully someone will let us know.

Answer (score 5):

Without loss of generality, assuming $a\leq b\leq c\leq d$ , we can determine the range of $a,b,c,d$

```
Through[{Floor@*MinValue, Ceiling@*MaxValue}[{#, a + b + c + d == 711,
      a*b*c*d == 100^3 711, 0 < a <= b <= c <= d}, {a, b, c, d}]] & /@ {a, b, c, d}
```

> {{74, 131}, {107, 213}, {130, 248}, {212, 320}}

$c, d$ can be represented by $a, b$

```
Solve[{a + b + c + d == 711, a*b*c*d == 100^3 711}, {c, d}][[1]] /. 
  Sqrt[_] :> Sqrt[delta] // Simplify
```

> $\left\{c\to \frac{1}{2} \left(-\frac{\sqrt{\text{delta}}}{a b}-a-b+711\right),d\to \frac{1}{2} \left(\frac{\sqrt{\text{delta}}}{a b}-a-b+711\right)\right\}$

So we can get the answer by enumerating $a$ and $b$

```
Compile[{}, Module[{delta, c, d, tol = 1.*^-10},
    Do[delta = a b (a b (a + b - 711)^2 - 4 100^3 711);
     If[delta >= 0,
      c = 1/2 (711 - a - b - Sqrt[delta]/(a b)); 
      d = 1/2 (711 - a - b + Sqrt[delta]/(a b));
      If[a <= b && Abs[Round@c - c] < tol && Abs[Round@d - d] < tol &&
         130 < c < 248 && 212 < d < 320, Print[Round@{a, b, c, d}]];
      ]
     , {a, 74., 131}, {b, 107., 213}]
    ]][] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {120, 125, 150, 316}
> {0.0021569, Null}

If you need all possibilities
`Permutations[{120, 125, 150, 316}]`

> {{120,125,150,316},{120,125,316,150},{120,150,125,316},{120,150,316,125},{120,316,125,150},{120,316,150,125},{125,120,150,316},{125,120,316,150},{125,150,120,316},{125,150,316,120},{125,316,120,150},{125,316,150,120},{150,120,125,316},{150,120,316,125},{150,125,120,316},{150,125,316,120},{150,316,120,125},{150,316,125,120},{316,120,125,150},{316,120,150,125},{316,125,120,150},{316,125,150,120},{316,150,120,125},{316,150,125,120}}

Comment: Thank you so much for your contribution.  I will definitely study this solution.  I have a long way to go to master when to compile and when not to compile.  Also, the underlying mathematics here will take me a second to pick up.  Who knew such a 'simple' puzzle could get such advanced treatment?

Comment: Wait, the range for 'd' was determined to be [212, 320], yet the Do loop uses [21, 320].  I presume that is a typo?

Comment: @JoeMarino This is a typo.

Comment: If all three steps are timed together, the total time is `0.217672` sec., and the first step is rather an essential step in the solution.

Answer (score 3):

NMinimize can do the job in 4 seconds.

( For some parameters, you have to play around with WorkingPrecision, MaxIterations and PrecisionGoal. )

```
prices = {a, b, c, d};
pints = # \[Element] Integers & /@ prices;
ppos = 0 < # < 711 & /@ prices;
ptotal = Total[prices] == 711;
pprod = Times @@ prices == 100^3 711;

jj = Join[pints, ppos, {ptotal}, {pprod}]

(*   {a \[Element] Integers, b \[Element] Integers, c \[Element] Integers, 
 d \[Element] Integers, 0 < a < 711, 0 < b < 711, 0 < c < 711, 
 0 < d < 711, a + b + c + d == 711, a b c d == 711000000}   *)

(nmin = NMinimize[{a, jj}, prices, MaxIterations -> 500, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 30]) // Timing

(*   {4.234, {125.000000000000000000000000000, {a -> 125, b -> 316, 
   c -> 120, d -> 150}}}   *)

(nmin = NMinimize[{d, jj}, prices, MaxIterations -> 500, 
    WorkingPrecision -> 200, AccuracyGoal -> 1, 
    PrecisionGoal -> 1]) // Timing

(*   {4.14, {120.\
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000\
000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, {a -> 125, 
   b -> 316, c -> 150, d -> 120}}}   *)
```